# How to set the log level on a class in log4j2 properties

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

In log4j I could specify a class in the properties file to log at the debug level like this:

```
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.mypackage.ClassName=DEBUG
```

How do I do this in log4j2?  Note I still need to use the new property file (not xml or json).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As the [log4j2 configuration documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) states

> As of version 2.4, Log4j now supports configuration via properties
>   files. **Note that the property syntax is NOT the same as the syntax
>   used in Log4j 1.**

It then provides a substantial example for all types of configuration elements.

Concerning your question, you need to specify your loggers in a `loggers` element, then configure each of them. For example

```
loggers = mine

logger.mine.name = com.mycompany.mypackage.ClassName
logger.mine.level = DEBUG
```

---

[Note that log4j2 looks for a `.properties` file on the classpath by default.](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration)

> If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory
>   will look for `log4j2.properties` on the classpath.

But you can also configure the location yourself. You can use the system property

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=conf/log4j.properties
```

with an appropriate path.

Comment: Does this mean that I need another 3 lines to specify different logging for another class?  For example, (1) loggers = myOther
(2) logger.myOther.name = com.mycompany.otherpackage.OtherClassName
(3) logger.myOther.level = INFO

Comment: @kc2001 You can provide multiple loggers in `loggers` as a comma separated list. The other properties will need their own lines.

Comment: As of `v2.6`, it is no longer required to list your loggers in the `loggers`. Log4j2 will infer the names automatically ([source](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties)).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring boot, you can use

```
logging.level.com.mycompany.mypackage.ClassName=DEBUG
```

in [application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html).